# Filtering divs by classes with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on filtering a pile of divs with checkboxes.

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li>
        <table id="filters_opt" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="Familien" id="filter-Familien" />
        <label for="filter-Familien">Familien/Kinder</label></td>

        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="Jugend" id="filter-Jugend" />
        <label for="filter-Jugend">Jugend</label></td>

        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="Senioren" id="filter-Senioren" />
        <label for="filter-Senioren">Senioren</label></td>

        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="Musik" id="filter-Musik" />
        <label for="filter-Musik">Musik</label></td>
        <td rowspan="3" align="center" id="filter_anwenden_big"><input type="button" class="send_button" value="Filter anwenden"></td>
       <tr>
</table>   
    </li>
</ul>



$("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {

   $("." + $(this).val()).show();

});
```

so far this is showing all divs with the classes selected by the checkboxes. But I can't seem to wrap my head around the following:

When I have these conditions:
class A
class B
or a combination ie classes A + B + C

Shouldn't the results get smaller? It seems to always display all divs from class A, all divs from class B and all divs from class C. But I'd like to display results like only divs that contain class A + B. And not A and B seperately.

Any ideas my fellow coders?

[JsFiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/d621ageL/) - Here's a working example. If I check on "Erwachsene" and "Flingern" it shouldn't show the "only Flingern" example nor the "Senioren - Flingern - Duesseltal" example.

What I'm trying to achieve is that the more checkboxes I activate, the more results will be narrowed down until only few are left.

With my current code it just shows too much results. Because it shows all divs with the class "Flingern" and all with the class "Erwachsene".

Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question and create a stacksnippets to demonstrate issue? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It depends on what values of your checkboxes are.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'm fairly new to this. I put in some of the html. I'll try to make a stacksnippet!

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean (stacksnippet would help!), but if it helps, `$(".a.b")` selects things that have both classes while `$(".a .b")` (with a space) selects things that have either class.

Comment: You need to attach a function to the clicking of the button `$('.send_button').click(function() {
  $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    $("." + $(this).val()).show();

  });
})`

Comment: added a JSFiddle! Hope this helps to understand me, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your selector query like this :

```
    $(".send_button").click(function() {

      $(".filter").hide();

      var classes = ['.filter'];

      $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
               classes.push($(this).val());
           });

      $(classes.join('.')).show();

      return false;
   });
```

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d621ageL/1/

Comment: oh, this is perfect! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: if it solved your issue, please mark it as a correct answer. Thank You